# Application.LocalUserAppDataPath different when associated file is opened

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, windows-7

When I open a VB.NET application from start menu and associated file, I get a different LocalUserAppData path. This is also giving me a different my.settings.

```
Application.LocalUserAppDataPath
```

Start Menu

> C:Users\user name\AppData\Local\App\2.0\data\obfuscated\obfuscated\obfuscated\Data

Associated File

> C:\ProgramData\Company Name\Application Name\1.0.0.0